# Is there a way to store a random number for using in the subjectline and HTML body?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

I am using the script and modified it to my needs:

```
    %%[
/*Sets de AB */ 
set @modtarget = AttributeValue("_customObjectKey")

if not empty(@modtarget) then 

  if mod(@modtarget, 2) == 0 then  /* even */
    set @randomAB = "1"
  else /* oneven */
    set @randomAB = "2"
  endif

endif
]%%
```

In my sendlog the field randomAB exists. I am using this so I can query the sendlog with data views. It works but ofcourse every record will be stored with 1 or 2 in the randomAB field within the sendlog even when I am not using it in an AB test. Is there a way to only add the 1 or 2 to a specific piece so that not every email results in a 1 or 2. For example:

I have a dynamic title in my email. There are, lets say, 10 different titles. Based on the data you will got one of these titles. I want to AB test title 1. So only the records that are using version 1 or 2 of title 1 should be stored with 1 or 2 in the randomAB field within the sendlog. The default of randomAB in the sendlog is set to 0. So every record that has title 2-10 should be stored with 0 in the sendlog (hopefully this make sense). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate the test case using the `_customObjectKey` -- the hidden identity number associated with the row in the data extension.  This key value would would remain associated with the send to a specific subscriber as long as the data extension is not overwritten.

If the result of the [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo) operation is even, use subject #1; if odd, use subject #2:

```ampscript
%%[

set @ck = AttributeValue("_customObjectKey")

set @subject = "default"

if not empty(@ck) then 

  if mod(@ck, 2) == 0 then  /* even */
    set @subject = "subject 1"
  else /* odd */
    set @subject = "subject 2"
  endif

endif

]%%
```

Reference:

- [mod()](https://ampscript.guide/mod)

Comment: Works like a charm. Noticed one thing. When I select a data extention with records created manually it doesn't work. If I select a data extension that is pupulated via a import   it works fine. Is my conclusion correct that the _customObjectKey only exists when data is imported via a import or API injection?

Comment: I haven't encountered missing _customObjectKey values.  You should be able to verify with a retrieve of a DataExtensionObject (aka row) via SOAP API or WSProxy.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. In the script I target directly the field in the sendlog. I changed the field randomAB in the script to something else and use that for targetting the right title. In the ampscript of the titles I added the randomAB field so it only writes 1 or 2 when the subjectline is targetting.